# Gröbner bases over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, principal-ideal-domains, groebner-basis

Gröbner bases provide us with suitable polynomial generating sets, for ideals of $k[x,y,z,..]$ where $k$ is a field.

When applied to linear polynomials the method reduces to Gauss-Jordan elimination (for bringing a matrix to row-echelon form) and when applied in $k[x] \ $, i.e. to the ideal generated by univariate polynomials, it reduces to the usual Euclidean division in $k[x]$.

**My question here is:** can anyone give an account of how the method works for polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$? In other words, how can we compute the Gröbner basis of the ideal generated by two integer polynomials $f(x)$, $g(x)$?

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/search?safe=off&q=boolean+groebner+basis

Comment: @arthur I don't get what has to do a boolean GB with GB over $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @arthur: Neither do I.

Comment: Boolean is $\mathbb{Z}[2]$

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a ring.  https://www.google.com.au/search?safe=off&q=groebner+basis+on+rings

Comment: @arthur No, a boolean ring is a ring in which every element satisfies $x^2=X$.

Comment: @Fredrik Meyer : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring

$$.$$

In mathematics, a Boolean ring R is a ring for which $x^2 = x$ for all x in R, such as the ring of integers modulo 2.

$$.$$

o.k. so $\mathbb{Z}[2]$ is just one instance of a Boolean ring.

Comment: @arthur You're referring to $\mathbb Z$ modulo 2?

Comment: @Fredrik Meyer - yes.